# Task bar pinned icon becomes blank while application upgrade

Tags: wix, taskbar, shortcut-file, wix3.10

I am using WIX 3.10. My application's icon which is pinned to task bar becomes blank after the application is upgraded.Is there any solution to fix this issue?

Comment: And the shortcut still works after the upgrade?

Comment: No its not working.

Comment: Maybe the upgrade removed the file the shortcut tries to open? (The file that is pinned to the taskbar is the file that was running when you pinned it - it might not be the file that actually launches\starts you application)
Try to re-pin your application to the taskbar and see where the shortcut actually points and compare it to the broken shortcut.